# tensorflow batch normalization freeze

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow, tensorflowsharp

I'm trying to implement frozen graph on unity. But I have some error. I think the error related on batch normalization but I have no idea to solve this problem. 
When I train my model *BN* is necessary so I can't just remove the *BN*.

So I have to find some way to how do proper freeze the graph with *BN* without causing error when it implement on unity. Any Idea?

I had already some researches for this problem I know not only the *BN* cause this error also the dropout has same problem.

*note: I'm using tensorflowsharp. network is based on ResNet34 with little modified.*

```
error: TFException: Input 0 of node bn2c_branch2a/Assign was passed float from bn2c_branch2a/mean:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.
TensorFlow.TFStatus.CheckMaybeRaise (TensorFlow.TFStatus incomingStatus, System.Boolean last) (at <013bee3700ac45f2a3b8843fa1d4d914>:0)
TensorFlow.TFGraph.Import (TensorFlow.TFBuffer graphDef, TensorFlow.TFImportGraphDefOptions options, TensorFlow.TFStatus status) (at <013bee3700ac45f2a3b8843fa1d4d914>:0)
TensorFlow.TFGraph.Import (System.Byte[] buffer, TensorFlow.TFImportGraphDefOptions options, TensorFlow.TFStatus status) (at <013bee3700ac45f2a3b8843fa1d4d914>:0)
TensorFlow.TFGraph.Import (System.Byte[] buffer, System.String prefix, TensorFlow.TFStatus status) (at <013bee3700ac45f2a3b8843fa1d4d914>:0)
DeepGes.GClassifier.InitClassifier () (at Assets/Scripts/Gesture_Main/GClassifier.cs:42)
G_Game.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Gesture_Main/G_Game.cs:67)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure on what you are asking or working on, however I did some research for you to hopefully point you in the right direction.

[Good Audience - TensorFlow + Unity: How to set up a custom TensorFlow graph in Unity](https://blog.goodaudience.com/tensorflow-unity-how-to-set-up-a-custom-tensorflow-graph-in-unity-d65cc1bd1ab1)

There is a guy here who is an ML engineer, so maybe try asking him.
[Unity Forums - Using Tensorflow's inference graph in Unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1517623/using-tensorflows-inference-graph-in-unity.html)

Best of luck.